# Watch what's happening or see what's happening?

Tags: american-english

Which one is correct? If neither, what should the verb be?

Comment: If you're talking to someone else, imperative *Watch what happens next* is probably more likely, but if you're talking about something *you* witnessed, you'd probably say *I saw what happened*. They're pretty much interchangeable in such contexts, but ***watch*** often implies a more *volitional, purposeful* action (similar to the difference with ***hear, listen***).

Comment: "What what happens" infers paying attention, whereas "see what happens"  points out the result of a separate action.